# Relating the order of the class of an ideal in $\operatorname{Cl}_K$ to the class number of a finite extension $L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a non-zero ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\mathfrak{a}^m = (a)$ for some $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$.

> Does there exist a finite extension $L/K$ such that $\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_L$ is principal?

The answer is yes; one can take $L = K(\sqrt[m]{a})$ (or indeed the Hilbert class field of $K$).

Consider instead the induced homomorphism $\varphi: \operatorname{Cl}_K \to \operatorname{Cl}_L$. Then the image of $[\mathfrak{a}^m]$ is obviously $[\mathcal{O}_L]$ under $\varphi$. If, however, $(m , h_L) = 1$ then this guarantees that $\varphi([\mathfrak{a}]) = [\mathcal{O}_L]$, motivating the question

> Given a number field $K$ and a positive integer $m$, is there a finite extension $L/K$ such that $(m, h_L) = 1$ and $h_L \neq 1$?

Obviously if I pick $m$ as the order of the class of an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$ then this answers the original question in a cool way, but I don't expect that I'd be able to prove this with the tools I have (if it's not a stupid question).

Comment: Consider a number field $K$ with infinite $2$-class field tower and $m=2$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I think this might come under "tools that I don't have" sadly. Would you be able to point me to a reference for $p$-Class fields? :)

Comment: If $K$ is a field with infinite 2-class field tower then every finite extension of $K$ has even class number. Look for class field tower and shafarevich.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer brilliant, thanks a lot :)